# Flutter cast runs in development but crashes in production

Tags: flutter, dart, casting, environment

Casting null as a String is allowed in my local flutter environment during debugging. However, when deployed to production, the same typecast is treated as a crashing exception.

The code can be translated to the following:

```
    final dynamic test = null as String;
    print(test);
```

The actual code is generated by the json_serializable package (https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable), thus alternating the code itself is not possible.

My local environment described through flutter doctor:
[Local flutter environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7W78a.png)

The production crash can be simulated in Dartpad https://dartpad.dev/?channel=old

What differs the environments? I'd like the development environment to throw the error, so it's spotted & fixed before being pushed to production state.

I've tried comparing the production environment with the development environment, but found no major differentiations that could explain the behaviour.

Comment: What is the code you wrote that caused `json_serializable` to generate that?

Comment: The code I've provided resembles the generated code from json_serializable for a class with a non-nullable field. An official example can be found under "Example" at https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable looking at the Person class fields "firstName" and "lastName"

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.  Although you cannot alter the generated code, it does not mean that you aren't doing something wrong to cause incorrect code from being generated.  I haven't tried it yet, but I rather doubt that the official example generates such code.

Comment: Also, note that the `json_serializable` example states for the `firstName` and `lastName` fields: "The generated code assumes these values exist in JSON." If those entries are missing in the JSON data, yes, you'll end up with the equivalent of `null as String`.  If those entries might be missing, you must use nullable types instead.

Comment: The reproducible example is a Flutter project corresponding to my documented environment with the provided code placed in main.dart. Executing should result in dart printing "null", while the same code crashes in dartpad with a nearly identical environment.

You are very right that the package would never generate a null typecast directly and that nullable class fields indeed should be marked as nullable. However, I have no API-documentation to determine nullable values. Either way, I'd like my dev environment to crash with the same code, that crashes my production environment.

Comment: It seems to me that your production environment is giving you JSON data with missing entries.  Figure out why you get different JSON data in the different environments.   Or make *all* fields nullable, because IMO clients shouldn't necessarily trust the server since server output can change, especially when you have no API documentation.  `null as String` is *not* a reproducible example.  It reproduces the *error*, which is just a *symptom*.  It doesn't help anyone isolate the *cause* for having different behaviors in different environments.

Comment: This is a great comment. We've been discussing the error within the dev team and we agree with the idea of clients not trusting their servers. We will be implementing all serializing of data from our servers as nullable. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As jamesdlin pointed out in the comments, the client should not trust the server to provide reliable data. Implementing client side null-checks and fallback makes the client more resilient.

Hence all fields declared using json_serializable shuold be marked as nullable.

Answer (score 1):

instead of using `as` you can use `.toString()`

```dart
  final dynamic test = null.toString();
```

While also using variable,

```dart
  final String data = "${model.filed}";
```

Comment: That would be a great solution were it not for the code to be uneditable, since it's generated by the json_serializable flutter package.

Comment: on that case you can wrap the usecase method with try-catch block,

Comment: Yes that would indeed prevent the exception to crash in production, but the following application state would be invalid, since the cast went bad. I'd like the development environment to throw the error for it to be spotted & fixed.